# 'Global name not defined' concept in python

Tags: python, global-variables

I am learning Python and have read blogs about this error, but I am still not able to understand this clearly yet. This is a snippet of the code I am writing:

```
for i in included:
    global signs,accounts, regions
    global sign_name, acc_name, rg_name
    if type == "regions":
        regions = i
        rg_name = regions['data']['region']
    if type == "accounts":
        accounts = i
        acc_name = accounts['data']['account']

    print("Stopping account " + acc_name + " in region " + rg_name)
```

NameError: global name 'acc_name' is not defined.

I am using Python 2.7
If anyone can help me understand the concept of global names and initiation in Python, it would be great. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did any of these answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No worries :) welcome to Python!  It's throwing that error because it's looking for a global variable that doesn't exist -- and the reason it doesn't exist is because you're not hitting the `if type == "accounts"` condition!

try this:

```
for i in included:
  global signs,accounts, regions
  global sign_name, acc_name, rg_name
  regions = "no region yet"
  acc_name = "no acc_name yet"
   if type == "regions"
     regions = i
     rg_name = regions['data']['region']
   if type == "accounts"
     accounts = i
     acc_name = accounts['data']['account']

   print("Stopping account " + acc_name + " in region " + rg_name)
```

That will clear the error and at least let you see what other bugs may be popping up :)

I'll also point out, as I'm sure you will hear from others, there's no reason for you to be declaring global variables in this context.  It was initially saying "can't find global variable" because before you put in the `global` keywords, it wasn't triggering on the `if` statement and so first it checked the `locals()` variables, and not finding it, searched for the `globals()` variables, and not finding it kicked and error.

You can remove the `global` variables and it will work fine like so:

```
for i in included:
   regions = "no region yet"
   acc_name = "no acc_name yet"
   if type == "regions"
     regions = i
     rg_name = regions['data']['region']
   if type == "accounts"
     accounts = i
     acc_name = accounts['data']['account']

   print("Stopping account " + acc_name + " in region " + rg_name)
```

Another quick note, never the `type` as a variable... use `type_` instead.  The reason is `type` is a `builtin` Python function and if you use `type` as a variable you are accidentally aliasing that builtin name.

Finally, just to clean up the script a little more:

```
# only use "i" when you're using numbers, otherwise just call it 
# the name of the data you're using :)
for account_data in included:
   regions = "no region yet"
   acc_name = "no acc_name yet"
   if type_ == "regions"
     rg_name = account_data['data']['region']
   if type_ == "accounts"
     acc_name = account_data['data']['account']

   # here's an example of Pythonic string formatting :)
   print("Stopping account {} in region {}".format(acc_name, rg_name))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a great explanation, now it makes things clear

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see is that you never predefine acc_name in both local and global scopes. 
The error wouldn't exist if you add `acc_name = 'something'` anywhere before `print("Stopping account " + acc_name + " in region " + rg_name)`.

The error in your code is that `if type == "accounts"` but the type wasn't 'accounts' so `acc_name = accounts['data']['account']` never ran.

Try this:

```
for i in included:
   global signs,accounts, regions
   global sign_name, acc_name, rg_name

   if type == "regions":
       regions = i
       rg_name = regions['data']['region']
   else:
       rg_name="No regions" #backup str
   if type == "accounts":
       accounts = i
       acc_name = accounts['data']['account']
   else:
       acc_name="No accounts" #backup str

   print("Stopping account " + acc_name + " in region " + rg_name)
```

This way there will be no errors

I dont know if that was your code but `global` command only need to be used inside functions for that it is not necessary to use it elsewhere.

and as a side note, a little more code would be appreciated and type isn't a good variable because it is also a builtin method.

Answer (score 2):

*Before* you use the global variable `acc_name` in your function for reading, it must be first initialized somewhere: either outside of the function or inside it. If `type == "accounts"`, then the variable would be initialized, but if it is not, it wouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I defined them outside of the function and it works