# NameError vs global NameError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to reproduce a bug that I've encountered that shows this:

> NameError: global name 'sdrent' is not defined

However, if I open up the interpreter and type in sdrent, I get the following error:

```
>>> sdrent
NameError: name 'sdrent' is not defined
```

What is the difference between `NameError: global name...` and `NameError: name...`, and how would I reproduce the former?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916300/global-name-not-defined-concept-in-python

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica 2.7.10 (don't laugh -- it's the program I have to debug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPython has two opcodes used for global variable lookups, [`LOAD_GLOBAL`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.10/Python/ceval.c#L2086) and [`LOAD_NAME`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.10/Python/ceval.c#L2044). `LOAD_NAME` looks for a local variable before a global variable, while `LOAD_GLOBAL` goes straight to globals. `LOAD_NAME` is primarily useful for class statements, but in the absence of a `global` declaration, the compiler also happens to emit `LOAD_NAME` for global variable lookups at module level.

Back before Python 3.4, `LOAD_GLOBAL` used to say `global name 'whatever' is not defined` when the lookup fails, and `LOAD_NAME` used to say `name 'whatever' is not defined`. This got [changed](https://bugs.python.org/issue17032) when someone argued that "global" was confusing for cases where someone mistyped a local variable name.

You're on Python 2.7. When you run a variable lookup for a nonexistent name at top level, you get the `LOAD_NAME` error message, but inside a function, you get the `LOAD_GLOBAL` error message, which still says "global" on Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this happens in the context of a function or method, where the LEGB stops at G(lobal), knowing the builtins already and exits/complains at that scope.

For example, to reproduce:

```
>>> def hi():
...     sdrent
...
>>> hi()
NameError: global name 'sdrent' is not defined
```

Or even simpler:

```
>>> (lambda: sdrent)()
NameError: global name 'sdrent' is not defined
```

And in a class method:

```
>>> class X:
        def __call__(_): sdrent
>>> X()()
NameError: global name 'sdrent' is not defined
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with "knowing the builtins already". The lookup does actually continue to the built-ins, because even if it tried to cache the fact that there's no `sdrent` built-in, something could have added an `sdrent` to the built-ins in the meantime.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I see, maybe I should add that in to clarify that it does check that, though the error message doesn't mention that.

Comment: (There is actually a global/builtin variable cache optimization on newer Python versions based on dict version identifiers, but it only triggers for cases where the lookup succeeds, not for NameErrors.)